# Should I use Angular for a local only NW.js project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller, node-webkit, nw.js

I want to build a mid-size application using NodeJS and NW.js (formerly known as node-webkit). The application will grab some data from the internet but isn't talking with one special service which is under my control.

Is it a good idea to use AngularJS nevertheless or is the MVC approach of Angular oversized if there isn't neither a database nor a webservice on the controller layer?

I think Angular would be really fine for databinding and GUI handling, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach for this kind of application.

Comment: Its not an answer but I want to know that what database approach are you thinking to use ? Relational or non relational ?

Comment: I wrote "neither a database nor..." - so there will be no database binding. Only some json-files for settings/configuration. But to answer your question - in other projects I used TingoDB, an embedded NoSQL database.

Comment: If you are comfortable with Angular, I don't see why not!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason not to use Angular in an nwjs project. I do it myself in [the app I just finished building](https://github.com/hearthpal/hearthpal-tracker). It's a local-only deck tracking app for hearthstone that never communicates over the internet at runtime. It only ever monitors a log file that is generated by the Hearthstone game. Since the way I'm display information to the user is still technically a web page with a full DOM, Angular makes perfect sense since I'm already comfortable using it.